# What species is this?

Tags: species-identification

We found this on a beach in the Bay of Lannion, Brittany, France. What is it? About 6 cm long.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is  the skeleton of [Sea Urchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_urchin) or sea hedgehog.

[image]

There are a lot of species (nearly 1000), so it is very difficult to identify just in five minutes, but in general you can start from knowing the Subclass Perischoechinoidea.

[image]

[image]